# Android unable to insert data into Mysql data base but data inserted in logcat

Tags: java, android, xml, json

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cleanindia");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security

$landmark = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['landmark']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);
$phonenumber= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phonenumber']);
$simnumber= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['simnumber']);
$imeinumber= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['imeinumber']);
$latitude= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['latitude']);




$sql="INSERT INTO details (land_mark, descrip, phonenum, sim, imei, lati)
VALUES ('$landmark', '$description', '$phonenumber', '$simnumber', '$imeinumber', '$latitude')";

/*$sql="INSERT INTO details (land_mark, descrip, phonenum, sim, imei)
VALUES ('abc', 'demo', '9876543210', '01234567890', '954756221102')";*/


$data = "Select * from details";
$datacount = mysqli_query($con,$data);
if (!mysqli_query($con,$data )) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo $data1 = mysqli_num_rows($datacount);


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i have a code where i need to send edit text values to server.but no problem with that. but when i post data to server it is not updating in server.it is just updating in logcat.so please help me.thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import com.igibpo.cleanindia.Details;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Details extends Activity {

    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpPost httppost;
    EditText lmark, des;
    String result;
    Button Submit;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String geted1, geted2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);

        lmark = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.landmark);
        des = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
        Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        httppost = new HttpPost("server");
        Submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                geted1 = lmark.getText().toString();
                geted2 = des.getText().toString();
                Log.i("LandMark", geted1);
                Log.i("Description", geted2);
                new getresult().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public class getresult extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Details.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Inserting Data....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("landmark", geted1));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", geted2));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"utf-8"));
                result = httpclient.execute(httppost,new BasicResponseHandler());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();

    }   

    }

}
```

Comment: kindly find the code above...@nag

Comment: it is showing InputEventReciver "Attempted to finish an input event but input event receiver has already been disposed"

Comment: show the code where this data is filled into db and also attach log.

Comment: 02-24 10:42:52.378: W/InputEventReceiver(28247): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
02-24 10:42:52.818: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28247): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-24 10:42:52.818: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28247): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
02-24 10:42:52.828: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28247): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection

Comment: 02-24 10:42:36.878: I/LandMark(28247): ben
02-24 10:42:36.878: I/Description(28247): benbena

Comment: is there no one to help me??

Comment: @user3693338 Please post the server side code.

Comment: kindly check the php code..@iRuth

Comment: after 3 days i made it. and now it works fine to me.i will post the code check it guys...

Answer (score 0):

Use the mysql statements In your code, don't forget to close the statement, Connections instances. close them properly, then only the changes will be saved in your database.

`UPDATE:`

use the below code for inserting data into your server database using jdbc statements

```
try{
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,dbuname,dbpass);
 Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
 stmt.executeUpdate("write insert statement here");

 //close the connection here
  con.close();
  stmt.close(); 

 }catch(Exception e){
   //write console statement here
 }
```

Comment: how to close the connection instances

Comment: i am not using connection here. i am using http post. please check that.else send me total code to post data from android to xampp server.

Comment: sqlite is the best database for android, try sqlite.

Comment: can you provide me an example@balayesu

Comment: follow the above tutorial for sqlite connection with android.